# How to set limit on horizontal rotation of Orbit Control in Three.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, three.js

Actually i have tried to set limit on horizontal rotation of orbit control but i haven't find any solution for limiting it within the given value like it happen in vertical rotation.

Please help me! I would appreciate your effort!

Answer (score 1):

Check [OrbitControls documentation](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/en/controls/OrbitControls), it is very complete.

For limit horizontal rotation you can add these lines:

```
controls.maxAzimuthAngle = Math.PI / 2;  
controls.minAzimuthAngle = Math.PI / 4;
```